# Buscar Numero repetido en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como puedo Buscar un numero repetido en una Tabla Items en diferentes Columnas  llamadas Gem1, Gem2, Gem3, Gem4, Gem5, Gem6 pero que se repiten en una misma fila.
ejemplo:

```
 UsuarioID, Gem1, Gem2, Gem3, Gem4, Gem5, Gem6
 0001       23    23    23    23    23    23
 0002       31    23    34    2     34    5
 0003       32    3     35    23    23    23
 0004       35    3     36    230   231   255
 0005       0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Necesito Hacer un select y un Update que me sustituya todos los números que se repiten en una misma fila y le coloque numero 0 agradezco de antemano.

Imaginando que es un Juego donde hay Tramposos que les gusta tener un numero repetido para salir "Ganadores" ejemplo **0001 Repite el numero 23 en toda sus seis Filas**, mientras **0002 repite 2 veces el numero 34** y **0003 repite el numero 23 tres veces** pero a su ves **0004 quien NO ES TRAMPOSO tiene sus números distintos y pasa la prueba  0005 cuyo numero por defauld en la data Base es Cero deberá omitirse** ya que significa que no posee Trampa aclarando que los numero que pueden repetirse van del 1 al 255

Mi pregunta es como puedo yo eliminar tramposos cuya tabla esta diseñada con exactitud asi?

Comment: si añadieras lo que has intentado aunque no funcionara, igual se veria mejor la pregunta *...misma fila y le coloque numero 0* he intentado bla. Saludos

Comment: Aunque creo que entiendo tu pregunta, puedo ver mas de una manera de interpretar como quieres que quede el resultado. ¿Puedes aclarar la pregunta agregando una segunda tabla que muestre el resultado deseado basado en la tabla que pusistes como ejemplo?

Comment: *Mi pregunta es como puedo yo eliminar tramposos*: ¿qué significa esto de forma concreta? No entiendo. Entiendo como defines lo que es un tramposo, pero todavía no entiendo lo que quieres hacer con ellos.  Como te mencioné en mi comentario anterior, lo ideal sería que incluyas una segunda tabla que, de forma concreta, muestre el resultado deseado.

Answer (score 1):

Una posible solución es generar una versión traspuesta de tus datos y hacer el conteo de duplicados en base a dicha transformación. Es decir, convertir la tabla a una *versión vertical* para facilitar las operaciones; por ejemplo:

```
id   gem    num
---- ------ -----
1    Gem1   23
1    Gem2   23
1    Gem3   23
1    Gem4   23
1    Gem5   23
1    Gem6   23
2    Gem1   31
. . .
```

El **único requisito** (y que no indicas en el ejemplo de los datos en tu pregunta) es la existencia de un campo llave que permita identificar cada fila (p.ej. un campo tipo `IDENTITY`).

A continuación se puede obtener el conteo (`COUNT`) de los datos en esa tabla traspuesta, agrupando por cada renglón (es decir, por la llave o `id`) y número, obteniendo algo así:

```
id   num   count
---- ----- -------
1    23    6
2    34    2
3    23    3
```

y finalmente utilizar dicho conteo para actualizar los datos en tu tabla original al valor deseado (cero).

Para ilustrar la solución preparé [éste código SQL](http://rextester.com/RFBY47259) para que lo veas en acción; el ejercicio utiliza tablas temporales para generar los datos intermedios; sin embargo, podría simplificarse el código.

**Nota:** La solución adjunta encontrará incluso varios conjuntos de números duplicados, es decir, para la siguiente línea de datos:

```
Gem1  Gem2  Gem3  Gem4  Gem5  Gem6
23    8     23    17    14    14
```

identificará tanto el número 23 como el 14 como duplicados y los actualizará finalmente también a cero.